# How can I truncate (substring) all values for a particular column of a table in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm fairly new to PostgreSQL. I'm working with a table that has not had a max-length (character count) enforced in the "title" column. The application needs it to be less than 1000 characters but some fields are at 1200, 1300 etc.

I'm quite familiar with mySql but I'm having a harder time picking up PostgreSQL.

If this was mySql I would so something like:

```
UPDATE TABLE entries SET title = LEFT(title,1000)
```

How can I accomplish the same thing with PostgreSQL?

I have  phppgadmin and the commmand line at my disposal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it's the same in postgresql

```
UPDATE TABLE entries SET title = LEFT(title,1000)
```

or you can do something like this

```
UPDATE TABLE entries SET title = substring(title from 1 for 1000)
```

[Here's](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) the doc about the string functions in postgresql

Comment: ah, well i feel dumb for not realizing it was the same. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL it could be:

```
UPDATE TABLE entries SET title = substring(title from 1 for 1000)
```

From the [pg documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html):

**Function** `substring(string [from int] [for int])` 
**Descript** `Extract substring` 
**Example**  `substring('Thomas' from 2 for 3)` 
**Result**    `hom`

Comment: No offense, but you just copied my query.. with the same link.. You even edited your answer at first cause after reading mine you realized it wasn't starting at zero. Any reason?

Comment: I really don't appreciate being called a cheater. No offense? Yeah. I actually found the same documentation you did. Google, go figure. I did did forget about the 1-based index but only decided to commit the answer while yours was deleted. No offense. And a downvote to boot? Thanks.

Comment: @Marc I chose your answer since it's basically the same and you answered first but mb not a good reason to downvote if that was u